# Twig dividing data into tables

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working on a webapplication but ive ran into a hiccup, I have gathered data from my database and displayed the records into a datatable, my problem is that I can not just have one table the client wants me to divide the table into multiple based on what interger is in a column(omloopNummer).

The best ive gotten so far is with the following code it wil split the table up into lets say 4 tables if the interger in the database wil go 1,2,3,4 but it wil only show 1 record in each table while it should be more.

If there is any other simple solution to this instead of using twig I would be happy to try it.

```
<div id="index" class="table-responsive">
{% set i = 1 %}
{% for duel in duels %}
    {% if duel.omloopNummer == i %}
        {% set i = i + 1 %}
<table id="" class="table display-" style="width: 90%; margin-top: 30px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Omloop</th>
            <th>Team 1</th>
            <th>vs</th>
            <th>Team 2</th>
            <th>Acties</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ duel.omloopNummer }}</td>
            <td>{{ duel.team1 }}</td>
            <td>vs</td>
            <td>{{ duel.team2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ include('duel/_delete_form.html.twig') }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHP to group `Duels` by `omloopNummer` in the controller before passing to twig.

```
$duels = $duelRepository->findAll();
$sorted = [];
foreach($duels as $duel){
  $sorted[$duel->getOmloopNummer()][] = $duel;
}

return $this->render('template.html.twig', [
  'duel_groups' => $sorted,
]);
```

Then in twig, loop through the sorted array building a table for each non-empty group and inside ***each*** `tbody` loop through the group.

```
{% for group in duel_groups %}
  ...
  {% if group is not empty %}
  <table>
    ...
    <tbody>
      {% for duel in group %}
        <tr>...</tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {% endif %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is good but i have to dynamicly create the tables as I cant know how many there wil be beforehand, any solution to that?

Comment: But you do know when you render the template. Check my edit,  I added twig conditions to only render the tables if they are not empty.

Comment: Hey, I might have formulated wrong in your example you are hardcoding tables 1 and 2 im looking for my tables to generate off of one templated table because there could be 4 or 5 but also 10 or 15.

Comment: Updated my answer, just a matter of looping logic. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: YES! Thank you so much this was exactly what I was looking for, you're a hero! works like a charm. I did have my looping logic wrong and I'm going to study this bit for a second so i fully understand thanks aigan!